# Mediation with interaction term

Tags: interaction, mediation

I am interested by explaining the effect of x on y via m (my mediator). I know how to build the models, comparing the b coefficients, running a model (e.g., with mediate() in R). Basically I want to answer the question "what part of the effect of x on y can be accounted by m". So I run:

1. y = b1*x
2. y = b1*x + b2*m
   and I copmare the two b1 coefficients by computing (b1 in equation 1 - b1 in equation 2)/(b1 in equation 1). Now I want to add the interaction between x and m, so:
3. y = b1*x + b2*m + b3*m*x
   Assuming that every term is significant, how can I interpret the b1 coefficient in equation 3 given that the coefficient change in every level of m? How can I tell what part of the effect of x on y can be imputed to m?

Comment: This is a moderated mediation, as you include the interaction term. As the [Wikipedia page on mediation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mediation_(statistics)#Criticisms_of_mediation_measurement) says, "the independent variable and mediator cannot interact" in a strict mediation model.

Comment: Modern causal mediation allows this: see [Valeri and VanderWeele (2013)](http://doi.apa.org/getdoi.cfm?doi=10.1037/a0031034) for an example and tutorial.